# Dictionary list/dict comparison

Tags: python

I would really appreciate any help on the below. I am looking to create a set of values with 1 name compiling all duplicates, with a second dict value to total another value from a list of dicts. i have compiled the below code as an example:

```
l = [{'id':  1, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '100', 'year': '2000', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id':  2, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2071', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id':  3, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '1220', 'year': '2076', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id':  4, 'name': 'cucumber', 'price': '90000000', 'year': '2080', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id':  5, 'name': 'pear', 'price': '1000', 'year': '2000', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id':  6, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2022', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id':  9, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '100', 'year': '2000', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 10, 'name': 'grape', 'price': '150', 'year': '2022', 'currency': 'eur'},
]

new_list = []
for d in l:
    if d['name'] not in new_list:
        new_list.append(d['name'])
print(new_list)

price_list = []
for price in l:
    if price['price'] not in price_list:
        price_list.append(price['price'])
print(price_list)
```

The out put i am hoping to achieve is:

```
[{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': <The total price for all apples>}]
```

Comment: You want the aggregate price by name? And what happens if the currencies differ?

Comment: Can't understand why u want to keep that format, isn't better to output a kind of 
{apple : total price}?

Comment: Why on earth do you want a list of two dictionaries with a single key-value-pair in each?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The out put i am hoping to achieve is:" Okay, so what is your **question** about this? It is [not possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/) to offer "any help", because that is not how the site works. Please try to explain: what happens when you try the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What don't you understand about this result, and exactly what do you want us to tell you about it?

Comment: For example, is the code only supposed to care about the apples? What is the **intended logic** behind the desired output?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a list with items looking more like `{'name': 'apple', 'price': 1720}`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary whose keys are the names and values are the list of prices. Then calculate the averages of each list.

```
d = {}

for item in l:
    d.setdefault(item['name'], []).append(int(item['price']))

for name, prices in d.items()
    d[name] = sum(prices)

print(d)
```

Actually, I thought this was the same as yesterday's question, where you wanted the average. If you just want the total, you don't need the lists. Use a `defaultdict` containing integers, and just add the price to it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for item in l:
    d[item['name']] += int(item['price'])

print(d)
```

Comment: You're missing `int()` to convert the price from a string to a number.

Comment: Although this doesn't make the OP's truely bizarre output of `[ {'name': 'apple'}, {'price': xxx} ]`, it creates a sane and sensible output instead.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, that will work. How would i go about adding say 'year' to this new dict:

    d.setdefault(item['name'], []).append(int(item['price']))

Comment: @MatBailie The OP's output makes no sense.

Comment: Where do you want the year? Do you want a different total for each year? Use the tuple `(item['name'], item['year'])` as the dictionary key.

Comment: d.setdefault(item['name'], [], item['year']).append(int(item['price']))

Comment: You need parentheses to make a tuple. `d.setdefault((item['name'], item['year']), [])`. Otherwise the `,` is the argument separator.

Comment: that doesnt look right in the output: 
``` for i in d:
    print(i)
print(type(i))```

Output: ``` ('apple', '2000')
('apple', '2071')
('apple', '2076')
('cucumber', '2080')
('pear', '2000')
('apple', '2022')
('grape', '2022')
<class 'tuple'>```

No sign of 'year'. I was expecting something close to  [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': <The total price for all apples>},{'currency:', eur}]

Comment: I get `{('apple', '2000'): [100, 100], ('apple', '2071'): [150], ('apple', '2076'): [1220], ('cucumber', '2080'): [90000000], ('pear', '2000'): [1000], ('apple', '2022'): [150], ('grape', '2022'): [150]}`

Comment: `d.setdefault((item['name'], item['year']), []).append(int(item['price']))`

Comment: Your expected result doesn't really make sense. Why do you have a different dictionary for each attribute, instead of putting all the data for apples together in one dictionary? You could use something like `{"apples": {"prices": [...], "currency": 'eur'}, "pear": {...}}`. I'll leave this as an exercise for you, it's not reasonable for you to expect someone to do all your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This method only requires one loop:

```
prices = {}

for item in l:
    prices.update({item['name']: prices.get(item['name'], 0) + int(item['price'])})

print(prices)
```

Just for fun I decided to also implement the functionality with the item and price dictionaries separated as asked in the question, which gave the following horrendous code:

```
prices = []

for item in l:
    # get indices of prices of corresponding items
    price_idx = [n+1 for n, x in enumerate(prices) if item['name'] == x.get('name') and n % 2 == 0]
    if not price_idx:
        prices.append({'name': item['name']})
        prices.append({'price': int(item['price'])})
    else:
        prices[price_idx[0]].update({'price': prices[price_idx[0]]['price'] + int(item['price'])})

print(prices)
```

And requires the following function to retrieve prices:

```
def get_price(name):
    for n, x in enumerate(prices):
        if n % 2 == 0 and x['name'] == name:
            return prices2[n+1]['price']
```

Which honestly completely defeats the point of having a data structure. But if it answers your question, there you go.

Answer (score -1):

This could be another one:

```
result = {}
for item in l:
    if item['name'] not in result:
        result[item['name']] = {'name': item['name'], 'price': 0}
result[item['name']]['price'] += int(item['price'])
```

Comment: `item` is not defined outside of the loop, did you mean to use an `else` clause?